# How can I project top 5 counts and sum the rest in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, count, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have the following documents:

```
_id: "Team 1"
count: 1200

_id: "Team 2"
count: 1170

_id: "Team 3"
count: 1006

_id: "Team 4"
count: 932

_id: "Team 5"
count: 931

_id: "Team 6"
count: 899

_id: "Team 7"
count: 895
```

The list is already sorted and everything, I just need to project this as an array of top 5 based on count and then the rest should be summed as 'others'. If possible I'd like to also add the percentage that each element in the list makes up of the full count. Like this:

```
[
  {"name":"Team 1", "count":1200, "percent":25},
  {"name":"Team 2", "count":1170,"percent":15},
  {"name":"Team 3", "count":1006,"percent":10},
  {"name":"Team 4", "count":932,"percent":5},
  {"name":"Team 5", "count":931,"percent":5},
  {"name":"Other", "count":1794, "percent":40}]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way to do it using `$facet` since `$setWindowFields` only  works with mongodb v5 or later

[mongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KmoStbs1P4u)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $sort: { count: -1 } },
    {
      "$facet": {
        others: [
          { "$skip": 5 },
          {
            "$group": {
              "_id": "others",
              "count": { "$sum": "$count" }
            }
          }
        ],
        top5: [ { "$limit": 5 } ]
      }
    },
    {
        "$project": { result: { "$concatArrays": [ "$others", "$top5" ] } }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": { totalCount: { "$sum": "$result.count" } }
    },
    { $unwind: "$result" },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: "$result._id",
        count: "$result.count",
        percent: {
          $round: [
            { "$multiply": [ { $divide: [ "$result.count", "$totalCount" ] }, 100 ] },
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ])
```

Comment: This is a nice one! just don't forget sort before

Comment: @nimrodserok thanks, the author said the list is already sorted that's why i didn't add the sort stage

Comment: @1sina1 You're completely correct, the list is indeed already sorted. Thank you, it works.

Answer (score 2):

Query

- `$setWindowFields` to sort and add the sort-rank to each document
- group by `null` with 3 accumulators

  - push the first 5 documents unchanged
  - sum the count of the rest (rank>5)
  - total sum
- `$map` to divide the counts with the total sum for the 5 top documents, to get the percentage also
- add also the percentage for the rest of documents
- unwind and replace the root, with those documents that have count and percentage

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=629f40fc91b564fc1e7e959b) (put the mouse at the end of each stage to see the stage in and out)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$setWindowFields": 
   {"output": {"rank": {"$rank": {}}}, "sortBy": {"count": -1}}},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": null,
    "top5": 
     {"$push": {"$cond": [{"$lte": ["$rank", 5]}, "$$ROOT", "$$REMOVE"]}},
    "other": {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$lte": ["$rank", 5]}, 0, "$count"]}},
    "all": {"$sum": "$count"}}},
 {"$project": 
   {"_id": 0,
    "docs": 
     {"$concatArrays": 
       [{"$map": 
           {"input": "$top5",
            "in": 
             {"name": "$$this._id",
              "count": "$$this.count",
              "percentage": 
               {"$multiply": [{"$divide": ["$$this.count", "$all"]}, 100]}}}},
         [{"name": "other",
            "count": "$other",
            "percentage": 
             {"$multiply": [{"$divide": ["$other", "$all"]}, 100]}}]]}}},
 {"$unwind": "$docs"}, {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$docs"}}])
```

Comment: Thank you @Takis, almost there, but there is a little issue. if you try to give Team 5 and Team 6 the same count you'll have 2 "rank 5". In that case I just want it to sort on '_id'.

Comment: As far as i know `$rank` doesn't work with more than 1 sorting field, one solution to that would be to add one extra field, with the sort-key(like add one extra field to each doc the combination of count and id) before the `$setWindowFields` but with this index use will be lost on sorting and might be slower.

Answer (score 1):

If you have mongoDB version 5.0 or higher you can use `$setWindowFields` like in @Takis nice answer. Otherwise, you can `group`, `$slice` and `$reduce` your way to the answer:

1. `$sort` to have the highest count on top and group to put them all in one array called `all` and to `$sum` up.
2. `$slice` the `all` array to keep only the top N.
3. `$reduce` the top N to sum them up.
4. Add the `others` to the top N array with count `sum-sum(topN)`
5. `$unwind` and format

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort: {count: -1}},
  {$group: {_id: null, all: {$push: "$$ROOT"}, sum: {$sum: "$count"}}},
  {$project: {_id: null, sum: 1,  res: {$slice: ["$all", 5]}}},
  {$project: {sum: 1,  res: 1, topN: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$res",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {$add: ["$$value", "$$this.count"]}
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {_id: 0, sum: 1, res: {
      $concatArrays: [
        [{_id: "other",  count: {$subtract: ["$sum", "$topN"]}}],
          "$res"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {$unwind: "$res"},
  {$project: {_id: "$res._id", count: "$res.count",
     percent: {  $round: [{$multiply: 
        [{$divide: ["$res.count", "$sum"]}, 100]}, 0]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ckTtF9IBlT0)